# Contar perdidos (NA) por variables (columnas)

Tags: r

Sé la cantidad de perdidos que tengo gracias a sum(is.na()) y complete.cases pero quiero saber en qué columnas están y si hay alguna variable que no tenga ningún NA, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo un `data.frame` como el siguiente:

```
set.seed(2021)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:5,NA), 20, replace = TRUE), ncol=5))
df

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 NA  4 NA  4  3
2 NA NA NA  3  4
3  2 NA  5  4  5
4  4  3  1  2  3
```

Con `sapply` buscamos los `NA`, con `colSums()` sumamos estos por columna y luego simplemente vemos aquellas columnas que tienen 1 o más `NA`

```
colSums(sapply(df, is.na)) > 0

   X1    X2    X3    X4    X5 
 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```